# Display contents of file(log file) from remote server in Oracle apex 20.1.0.00.13

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, host

I have my Oracle apex at a remote server A, also I have log files generated in the same remote server.

In Apex, there is an Interactive report with a column which should be a link to the individual log files in the sever.

I tried writing os_commands to connect the server and fetch the required log file, is there any other way to do it.
Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: @Littlefoot  If you could help me on this.. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bahadirs, could you help me with this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your log file through a link, it needs to be reachable via a webserver - go through the documentation of your webserver on how to serve that directory. Once you have that figured out you can generate the links in your report.

Comment: The webserver which has the log files also has the Oracle apex hosted there. My question is how to make the log files accesible to the Oracle apex. Thanks

Comment: As I said, you can serve them through a webserver. Then you can access the log files from an url and make them available as link in your report. Research how to make the directory where the logs are stored available through a webserver.

Comment: Similar question just asked today - check the answer, it is similar to what I suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490093/download-files-with-url-from-server-via-apex

Comment: I cannot figure out how to serve the files from server to the Apex. Could you please let me know how you did it.Thanks

Comment: Google "webserver static resources" - this is the most basic use of a webserver. You cannot do this in apex, itself, you need to do configure this separately. That other question explains in detail how it can be achieved. 
I have not done this myself, but that is how I would do it.