# Download files with URL from Server via APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, tomcat9

I'm trying to create a function that download files that are on the server with URL.
I have APEX running on Tomcat 9. On the server there is a path /folder/files that contains files i wanna download with url. I found that for example I can download files from /i/ folder with URL easilly with for example http://{host}:{port}/i/css/apex.css. I tried to create a shortcut to /folder/files in that folder.
Now there is a path ./i/files/. When I'm typing http://{host}:{port}/i/files/file1.pdf I get an 404.

How can I manage this or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simples solution. Just add to the server.xml line

```
<Context docBase="/folder/files" path="/files"/>
```

Now you must just remember to users have the privilage to read/execute/search from this path (the same owner, or the privilage for group or others).
Now I can easily use the url in APEX (http://{host}:{port}/files/file1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

APEX isn't designed to serve up static files in that way. The /i/ directory structure is pre-defined and doesn't necessarily point to a physical location on the server like you'd think it would. Your best bet is to place your custom files on a separate web server (a lot of people use a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat, for example) and load them from there with a "normal" static URL.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I founded solution, check my answer.